# Return of a func

Tags: c++, return-value, rvalue, lvalue

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    Rectangle() {}
    Rectangle (int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {}
    int area() {return width * height;}
    friend Rectangle duplicate (const Rectangle&);
};

Rectangle duplicate (const Rectangle& param)
{
  Rectangle res;
  res.width = param.width*2;
  res.height = param.height*2;
  return res;
}

int main () {
  Rectangle foo;
  Rectangle bar (2,3);
  foo = duplicate (bar);
  cout << foo.area() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

There is a friend function in line 14. this function declares an object inside its body. and at the the end returns that object. Now I wonder if the return of this function is an rvalue or lvalue?

Comment: Just stepping by to tell u that using namespace std; is generally a bad practice. I think for your sample it's okay but just keep global namespace pollution in mind  :)

Comment: It's a copy, so that'd make it an rvalue. lvalue implies it has a name.

Why didn't you use an example like `A foo();`, _Is_ `A` _rvalue or lvalue?_

Comment: The result of `duplicate (bar)` is an rvalue. The variable `foo` is an lvalue.

Comment: On an unrelated note you should really initialize the `width` and `height` members even in the default constructor. Otherwise you risk using their uninitialized and *indeterminate* values. Using indeterminate values lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Elliott Lvalue doen't imply names. For example, "Hello world" is a lvalue expression without name.

Comment: @conko: I couldn't believe that `"Hello world"` was an lvalue expression, but you are absolutely right. After 40 years as a C programmer, some things can still surprise me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep it in mind that value category is a property of an expression, not "a value".

`res`, as an id-expr, is lvalue. However, the `duplicate (bar)` function call expression is a rvalue, for all the functions calls returning non-reference are prvalues.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if the return of this function is an rvalue or lvalue?

It is an **rvalue**. From [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> - a **function call** or an overloaded operator expression, **whose return type is non-reference**...

This means that the call expression `duplicate (bar)` is an `rvalue`.

---

Also note that `res` itself is an lvalue expression.

Comment: in the body of the dublicate. an object is declared. and this object is created as an lvalue. at the end of the func, that object is returned. that's why I think the returned object is rvalue.

Comment: @alirahimi `res` itself is an `lvalue` expression while the call expression `duplicate (bar)` is an `rvalue`.